# multiplying an dividing irrational numbers and quantifiers

Tags: arithmetic

I'm doing a homework assignment, and I am pretty sure that I know which answer they expected, but the problem made me start thinking more deeply about numbers.

So if you have an an arbitrary irrational number, is there a number which is equal to that number / 2?  Is there a number which is equal to that number times two?

For the latter, I would say yes.  For the first question, I've come to think no.  The reason being that I do not think that an irrational number can be divided evenly.  If irrational numbers cannot be divided evenly, then 2 times any number, no matter how close, will always be different than a rational number by some amount.  But then, if this is the case, then also that means that there was no such number that could have been multiplied by 2 to make the irrational number.  And to my knowledge, there is no irrational number which when multiplied by a rational number is not irrational. So 2 times an irrational number, is an irrational number, but that would then not be evenly divisible by 2.  This is a contradiction, so it would seem to follow that all irrational numbers must be evenly divisible.

Can anyone make sense of this for me.

Comment: Why exactly do you think something like $\frac{\pi}{2}$ doesn't exist?

Comment: For the same reason you cannot draw a perfect circle.  You can never have exactly half of PI.  At least that was what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any real number $x$, rational or irrational, $\frac{x}2=\frac12x$ is a real number, and $2\cdot\frac{x}2=x$. If $x$ is rational, $\frac{x}2$ is also rational; if $x$ is irrational, $\frac{x}2$ is also irrational; but in both cases it exists.

Your difficulty seems to arise from trying to apply the notion *evenly divisible* to real numbers in general, when in fact it applies only to integers. It is perfectly true that if $n$ is an integer, then there is an **integer** $m$ such that $n=2m$ if and only if $n$ is even, so that some integers — the odd ones — are not two times some integer; and it’s often useful to distinguish the even integers from the odd integers. The odd integers are, however, still two times some **rational** number, albeit not an integer. E.g., $5=2\cdot\frac52$.

When we move from the integers to the rational numbers, matters change: if $p$ is rational, so is $\frac{p}2$, so every rational number is twice some rational numbers. And when we move on to the real numbers, we retain this property: if $x$ is a real number, so is $\frac{x}2$, so every real number is twice a real number.